# Is it possible to refund discount coupon?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Is it possible to "refund" discount coupon in case if order is cancelled via admin?

I'll describe in more detail.

Discount code created and set at

> "Marketing" => "cart price rules"

**and**

> "uses per coupon" == 1

for customer. Customer placed order and used that discount code.
Then admin make this order cancelled. But discount code isn't available nevertheless customer actually didn't use that coupon.